# java restful services as jar dependency on a war

Tags: java, rest, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I have  two different maven modules in a project, one is ui  module with angular js stuff and one services module which has restful web services with jersey. My question here is, Is there anyway i can add this services module as dependency to ui module in the pom.xml  and use it from ui module as a service. Idea here is to not deploy both as different wars, but as one.

Comment: In the web module `pom.xml` add the service module dependency like `groupid` and `artifactid` and `varsion`

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your services module as JAR. pom.xml should contain:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

And

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Create libs folder in your main project and place there generated JAR file. Main project pom.xml should contain:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>install-external</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <configuration>
                <file>${basedir}/libs/your_service.jar</file>
                <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                <groupId>your_service</groupId>
                <artifactId>your_service</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

And

```
<!-- External lib -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>your_service</groupId>
    <artifactId>your_service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <!-- <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/your_service.jar</systemPath> -->
    <!-- <scope>system</scope> -->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done in my few projects,

1.First create a blank project which acts as a container/parent for both UI and Services components/projects using `modules` tag. You specify both `module` in it. You can call it APP.

To build your project, you build APP which in turns builds both modules and you deploy APP to server.

This is just a blank Maven project with only a `pom.xml`

Specify `packaging` as `war` in `pom.xml`

2.Specify service project as `dependency` to UI project.

3.Specify APP project as `parent` in both of service as well as UI project.

Hope this helps !!